# css styles not being shown on the page

Tags: css, node.js, typescript, webpack, visual-studio-2013

I'm working with VS2013 Update 5 and Node.js v16. I had started off by following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-nodejs-with-react-and-jsx?view=vs-2019) guide. I've tried to add in css to it by adding in `css-loader` and `style-loader` packages and had updated the webpack-config.js for the `.css` files. When I run `node_modules\.bin\webpack ./app.tsx --config webpack-config.js` I get:

[image: issue]

and then when I run the project it shows the page without the css styles applied to it. I'm assuming that just by having the .css files shown as built is not good enough as it's not green?

**webpack-config.js**

```
    module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: "./app.tsx",
    mode: "development",
    output: {
        filename: "./app-bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.Webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js', '.jsx', '.tsx', '.css']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'ts-loader'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**package-json**

```
{
  "name": "ProjectName",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "ProjectDescription",
  "main": "server.js",
  "author": {
    "name": "Author",
    "email": ""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "@types/prop-types": "^15.7.5",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.21",
    "@types/react-transition-group": "^4.4.5",
    "@types/scheduler": "^0.16.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
    "braces": "^2.3.1",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.4",
    "csstype": "^3.1.1",
    "express": "~4.17.1",
    "js-tokens": "^8.0.0",
    "path": "~0.12.7",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.5",
    "style-loader": "~0.8.3",
    "ts-loader": "~9.3.1",
    "ts-node": "~10.8.0",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "~5.0.0",
    "webpack-cli": "~4.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack-cli ./app.tsx --config webpack-config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  }
}
```

**EDIT 1**

I've tried adding in `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Component/Home.css"/> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Component/Forms.css" />` to index.html but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the `href` was wrong. It should have been `href="Components/Home.css"/>`. There was a clue in the browser console.